# Query Mongoose by passing JSON into Find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm hoping to query Mongoose like this:

```
Users.find({
    name: {
        first: 'John',
        last: 'Doe'
    }
}).exec(function(err, users){
    console.log(users);
});
```

But it looks like I have to format it this way to get a response:

```
Users.find({
    'name.first': 'John',
    'name.last': 'Doe'
}).exec(function(err, users){
    console.log(users);
});
```

Is there a way to use the first method? I'm hoping to simply pass a JSON object directly in without having to reformat.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do `Users.find({ name: { first: 'John', last: 'Doe' } }` if and only if there is an exact match. Which means that the name object contains only those fields with those values.

If you have:

```
name: {
    first: 'John',
    middle: 'Fearless',
    last: 'Doe'
}
```

Then attempting an exact match will fail. To do partial match on a subdocument you have to do like in your second example:

```
Users.find({
    'name.first': 'John',
    'name.last': 'Doe'
});
```

Docs from mongodb:

- Exact matches - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-exact-matches-on-subdocuments
- Partial matches - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-fields-of-a-subdocument